# UITableViewCell remove the white color between each row and show backgound image of UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

Here is my image of my app

[image: My app image]

As you can see there is white line in each row. How can I get out of that line.

Here is my code for cell that I've done

```
cell.backgroundView = [ [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"conta.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ]autorelease];   
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
cell.textLabel.text = [tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
tableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
return cell;
```

I need to wipe out the white line in each row. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In xib u can select separator style is none. this makes white line not to display

```
cell.backgroundView = [ [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"conta.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ]autorelease];   
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
cell.textLabel.text = [tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
tableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
return cell;
```

Answer (score 7):

Somewhere during the setup of your table view, you can set the separator style to "None".  This can be done either in the interface builder storyboard/nib, or it can be done in code with something like:

```
[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code for this,

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when the cell is not tall enough because you made the cell smaller but you forgot to set it smaller on the table or in the

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Or because you wanted to leave a little space between the cells so the background can be seen between them, what you actually see is the "white" of the table itself.

Remember that by default the UITableViews are solid white, so if you want the background to be seen between cells, you need to also set the table as "non opaque" and it's background color as a clear color.